# Resolution changes if TV is restarted

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv

I have MythTV connected to flat panel TV by HDMI.  The resolution is correct only if the startup sequence is: TV on, then start the MythTV computer.  With this sequence the resolution is 1280x720, which is correct, and fills the TV screen.

If the TV is now switched off, then back on, the picture is about half size.  The resolution has changed to `1920x1080`.

If the MythTV computer is started with the TV off, then the TV is turned on, the picture overflows the screen.  The resolution is 1600x1200 in that case.

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

has only one option for monitor size, `1280x720`

I added

Option `IgnoreEDID true`

to both the Device and Monitor sections of `xorg.conf`, but it made no difference.

How can I keep the resolution at 1280x720 after switching the TV off, then back on?

I found the resolution in the cases above by switching to backend and running

`xdpyinfo | grep -B2 resolution`.

System details:

Mythbuntu 12.04 64 bit
MythTV 0.26
CPU/GPU AMD Zacate E35M1-M PRO
TV - AOC Envision L32W761, using HDMI input